# Related to url rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

"I want to perform 301 redirect in my site. So,

1. example.com
2. http://example.com
3. http://www.example.com/default.aspx

it will redirect to www.example.com

Comment: You can do this in IIS with the URL-rewrite module.

Comment: That's nice.. What have you tried? Other than expecting an answer here of course.

Comment: hey sachin but how can i use this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Easiest would be to use the [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Alternatively, you could place a redirect in your `Global.asax.cs` file in `Application_BeginRequest`:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Equals("http://www.example.com/foo.aspx")) 
     { 
        string newUrl = "http://www.example.com"; 
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"; 
        Response.StatusCode = 301; 
        Response.StatusDescription = "Moved Permanently";  
        Response.AddHeader("Location", newUrl); 
        Response.End();
     }
}
```

Comment: If this is `ASP.NET` like your tags suggest, then you can just add your own to your solution and copy this code into it.